# Extracting paragraphs containing a particular string from a group of paragraph having all paragraphs with same start and end

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to Extract  paragraphs containing a particular string from a group of  paragraph having all paragraphs with same start and end

for example: In the below text, all the paragraphs' first line starts with "Thread" and last line starts with "Breadcrumb", Now I want to extract only those paragraphs which contains "string_to_be_searched"

```
 Thread 1398 (Thread name)
    data...
    Breadcrumb: some alpha numeric data

  Thread 1398 (Thread name)
    data...
    string_to_be_searched
    Breadcrumb: some alpha numeric data



  Thread 1398 (Thread name)
    data...
    Breadcrumb: some alpha numeric data

 Thread 1398 (Thread name)
    data...
    string_to_be_searched
    Breadcrumb: some alpha numeric data

 Thread 1398 (Thread name)
    data...
    Breadcrumb: some alpha numeric data
```

I have tried it using a regular expression but when I try it without g option it gives me first two threads and when I do it with g it gives me first 4 threads, instead it should give me only 2nd and 3rd thread.

```
var re = /(Thread[\s\S]*?sys_mlock[\s\S]*?Bread.*)/m;
```

Problem Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nR3qG9/2

Answer (score 1):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
/(\bThread ((?!\bBread)[\s\S])*string_to_be_searched((?!\bBread)[\s\S])*Bread.*)/g
```

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nR3qG9/6)

`((?!\bBread)[\s\S])*` is the key here which means match 0 or more characters (including newlines) that are not followed by another `Bread` pattern (your end block).

Comment: but it didn't capture the third para which also contains "string_to_be_searched"

Comment: Yes it is capturing that as well, you just need to use `g` (global) flag. See updated answer and demo.